# Ray - Sphere Intersection

Tags: java, opengl, math, vector, raycasting

i've recently been trying to detect if the player is "aiming" at an object, but i have a problem with the detection.

So here is the formula i've used :

```
(ray * (origin-center))^2 - ||origin-center||^2 + r^2 >= 0
```

where ray is the direction where the player aims (source http://antongerdelan.net/opengl/raycasting.html), origin is the position of the camera and center is the center of the sphere

i've found this formula there https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93sphere_intersection

this translate into java to

```
public boolean collideWithSphere(Vector3f c, Vector3f o, float r) {
    float delta = 0;
    Vector3f omc = Vector3f.sub(o, c);
    float b = Vector3f.Dot(ray, omc);
    delta = b*b-Vector3f.Dot(omc,omc)+r*r;
    return delta >= 0;
}
```

I've made a few mesurment and for me the problem is that `ray * omc` isn't `>=` to `||omc||` when the distance from the origin to the sphere is big since no component of ray is ever going to be exactly +-1.

Anybody have a way to fix that ?

Thanks

====================================

## EDIT

Okay so at the end of the day the i had to invert the y component of omc to get it to work, i don't quiet understand why but i'll deal with it.

Comment: How long is your `ray`? That is important, because you use a scalar product with the vector from camera to sphere. Also, your `omc` should be `cmo`, because you want to get the vector from the camera to the sphere center.

Comment: The ray is a unit vector. I think I already tried the cmo thing but it didn't worked out, but I can give it one more try.

Comment: @MartinHennig Length of the Ray is not a requirement. You compute it based off the direction from Origin; see my provided code below.

Comment: Why do you want that ray*omc be larger than omc² ??

Comment: "The problem is": what problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my current game engine, I am using these two classes for Ray->Sphere intersection testing.

BoundingSphere.cs

```
using System;
using OpenTK;

namespace DestinyEngine.Framework.Maths
{
    public struct BoundingSphere : IEquatable<BoundingSphere>
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// The sphere center.
        /// </summary>
        public readonly Vector3 Center;

        /// <summary>
        /// The sphere radius.
        /// </summary>
        public readonly float Radius;

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructs a bounding sphere with the specified center and radius.  
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="center">The sphere center.</param>
        /// <param name="radius">The sphere radius.</param>
        public BoundingSphere( Vector3 center , float radius )
        {
            this.Center = center;
            this.Radius = radius;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Test if a bounding box is fully inside, outside, or just intersecting the sphere.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="box">The box for testing.</param>
        /// <returns>The containment type.</returns>
        public ContainmentType Contains( BoundingBox box )
        {
            //check if all corner is in sphere
            bool inside = true;
            for( int index = 0; index < box.GetCorners().Length; index++ )
            {
                Vector3 corner = box.GetCorners()[ index ];
                if( this.Contains( corner ) == ContainmentType.Disjoint )
                {
                    inside = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if( inside )
            {
                return ContainmentType.Contains;
            }
            double dmin = 0;
            if( Center.X < box.Min.X )
            {
                dmin += ( Center.X - box.Min.X ) * ( Center.X - box.Min.X );
            }
            else if( Center.X > box.Max.X )
            {
                dmin += ( Center.X - box.Max.X ) * ( Center.X - box.Max.X );
            }
            if( Center.Y < box.Min.Y )
            {
                dmin += ( Center.Y - box.Min.Y ) * ( Center.Y - box.Min.Y );
            }
            else if( Center.Y > box.Max.Y )
            {
                dmin += ( Center.Y - box.Max.Y ) * ( Center.Y - box.Max.Y );
            }
            if( Center.Z < box.Min.Z )
            {
                dmin += ( Center.Z - box.Min.Z ) * ( Center.Z - box.Min.Z );
            }
            else if( Center.Z > box.Max.Z )
            {
                dmin += ( Center.Z - box.Max.Z ) * ( Center.Z - box.Max.Z );
            }
            return dmin <= Radius * Radius ? ContainmentType.Intersects : ContainmentType.Disjoint;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Test if a sphere is fully inside, outside, or just intersecting the sphere.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sphere">The other sphere for testing.</param>
        /// <returns>The containment type.</returns>
        public ContainmentType Contains( BoundingSphere sphere )
        {
            float sqDistance = DestinyEngineMath.DistanceSquared( sphere.Center , Center );
            if( sqDistance > ( sphere.Radius + Radius ) * ( sphere.Radius + Radius ) )
            {
                return ContainmentType.Disjoint;
            }
            else if( sqDistance <= ( Radius - sphere.Radius ) * ( Radius - sphere.Radius ) )
            {
                return ContainmentType.Contains;
            }
            else
            {
                return ContainmentType.Intersects;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Test if a point is fully inside, outside, or just intersecting the sphere.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="point">The vector in 3D-space for testing.</param>
        /// <returns>The containment type.</returns>
        public ContainmentType Contains( Vector3 point )
        {
            float sqRadius = Radius * Radius;
            float sqDistance = DestinyEngineMath.DistanceSquared( point , Center );
            if( sqDistance > sqRadius )
            {
                return ContainmentType.Disjoint;
            }
            else if( sqDistance < sqRadius )
            {
                return ContainmentType.Contains;
            }
            else
            {
                return ContainmentType.Intersects;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the smallest <see cref="BoundingSphere"/> that can contain a specified <see cref="BoundingBox"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="box">The box to create the sphere from.</param>
        /// <returns>The new <see cref="BoundingSphere"/>.</returns>
        public static BoundingSphere CreateFromBoundingBox( BoundingBox box )
        {
            Vector3 center = new Vector3(
                ( box.Min.X + box.Max.X ) / 2.0f ,
                ( box.Min.Y + box.Max.Y ) / 2.0f ,
                ( box.Min.Z + box.Max.Z ) / 2.0f );
            float radius = DestinyEngineMath.Distance( center , box.Max );
            return new BoundingSphere( center , radius );
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Compares whether current instance is equal to specified <see cref="BoundingSphere"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="other">The <see cref="BoundingSphere"/> to compare.</param>
        /// <returns><c>true</c> if the instances are equal; <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
        public bool Equals( BoundingSphere other )
        {
            return this.Center == other.Center && this.Radius == other.Radius;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Compares whether current instance is equal to specified <see cref="Object"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">The <see cref="Object"/> to compare.</param>
        /// <returns><c>true</c> if the instances are equal; <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
        public override bool Equals( object obj )
        {
            if( obj is BoundingSphere )
            {
                return this.Equals( ( BoundingSphere )obj );
            }
            return false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the hash code of this <see cref="BoundingSphere"/>.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Hash code of this <see cref="BoundingSphere"/>.</returns>
        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return this.Center.GetHashCode() + this.Radius.GetHashCode();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets whether or not a specified <see cref="BoundingBox"/> intersects with this sphere.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="box">The box for testing.</param>
        /// <returns><c>true</c> if <see cref="BoundingBox"/> intersects with this sphere; <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
        public bool Intersects( BoundingBox box )
        {
            return box.Intersects( this );
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets whether or not the other <see cref="BoundingSphere"/> intersects with this sphere.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sphere">The other sphere for testing.</param>
        /// <returns><c>true</c> if other <see cref="BoundingSphere"/> intersects with this sphere; <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
        public bool Intersects( BoundingSphere sphere )
        {
            float sqDistance = DestinyEngineMath.DistanceSquared( sphere.Center , Center );
            return !( sqDistance > ( sphere.Radius + Radius ) * ( sphere.Radius + Radius ) );
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a <see cref="String"/> representation of this <see cref="BoundingSphere"/> in the format:
        /// {Center:[<see cref="Center"/>] Radius:[<see cref="Radius"/>]}
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>A <see cref="String"/> representation of this <see cref="BoundingSphere"/>.</returns>
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "{Center:" + this.Center + " Radius:" + this.Radius + "}";
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Compares whether two <see cref="BoundingSphere"/> instances are equal.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="a"><see cref="BoundingSphere"/> instance on the left of the equal sign.</param>
        /// <param name="b"><see cref="BoundingSphere"/> instance on the right of the equal sign.</param>
        /// <returns><c>true</c> if the instances are equal; <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
        public static bool operator ==( BoundingSphere a , BoundingSphere b )
        {
            return a.Equals( b );
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Compares whether two <see cref="BoundingSphere"/> instances are not equal.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="a"><see cref="BoundingSphere"/> instance on the left of the not equal sign.</param>
        /// <param name="b"><see cref="BoundingSphere"/> instance on the right of the not equal sign.</param>
        /// <returns><c>true</c> if the instances are not equal; <c>false</c> otherwise.</returns>
        public static bool operator !=( BoundingSphere a , BoundingSphere b )
        {
            return !a.Equals( b );
        }
    }
}
```

Ray.cs

```
using System;
using OpenTK;
using OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL;

namespace DestinyEngine.Framework.Maths
{
    public struct Ray : IEquatable<Ray>
    {
        public readonly Vector3 Origin;
        public readonly Vector3 Direction;

        public Ray( Vector3 origin , Vector3 direction )
        {
            this.Origin = origin;
            this.Direction = direction;
        }

        public Ray( float originX , float originY , float originZ , float directionX , float directionY , float directionZ )
        {
            this.Origin = new Vector3( originX , originY , originZ );
            this.Direction = new Vector3( directionX , directionY , directionZ );
        }

        public override bool Equals( object obj )
        {
            return ( obj is Ray ) && this.Equals( ( Ray )obj );
        }

        public bool Equals( Ray other )
        {
            return this.Origin.Equals( other.Origin ) && this.Direction.Equals( other.Direction );
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return Origin.GetHashCode() ^ Direction.GetHashCode();
        }

        public float? Intersects( BoundingBox box )
        {
            const float epsilon = 1e-6f;
            float? tMin = null, tMax = null;
            if( Math.Abs( Direction.X ) < epsilon )
            {
                if( Origin.X < box.Min.X || Origin.X > box.Max.X )
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                tMin = ( box.Min.X - Origin.X ) / Direction.X;
                tMax = ( box.Max.X - Origin.X ) / Direction.X;
                if( tMin > tMax )
                {
                    var temp = tMin;
                    tMin = tMax;
                    tMax = temp;
                }
            }
            if( Math.Abs( Direction.Y ) < epsilon )
            {
                if( Origin.Y < box.Min.Y || Origin.Y > box.Max.Y )
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                float tMinY = ( box.Min.Y - Origin.Y ) / Direction.Y;
                float tMaxY = ( box.Max.Y - Origin.Y ) / Direction.Y;
                if( tMinY > tMaxY )
                {
                    float temp = tMinY;
                    tMinY = tMaxY;
                    tMaxY = temp;
                }
                if( ( tMin.HasValue && tMin > tMaxY ) || ( tMax.HasValue && tMinY > tMax ) )
                {
                    return null;
                }
                if( !tMin.HasValue || tMinY > tMin )
                {
                    tMin = tMinY;
                }
                if( !tMax.HasValue || tMaxY < tMax )
                {
                    tMax = tMaxY;
                }
            }
            if( Math.Abs( Direction.Z ) < epsilon )
            {
                if( Origin.Z < box.Min.Z || Origin.Z > box.Max.Z )
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                float tMinZ = ( box.Min.Z - Origin.Z ) / Direction.Z;
                float tMaxZ = ( box.Max.Z - Origin.Z ) / Direction.Z;
                if( tMinZ > tMaxZ )
                {
                    float temp = tMinZ;
                    tMinZ = tMaxZ;
                    tMaxZ = temp;
                }
                if( ( tMin.HasValue && tMin > tMaxZ ) || ( tMax.HasValue && tMinZ > tMax ) )
                {
                    return null;
                }
                if( !tMin.HasValue || tMinZ > tMin )
                {
                    tMin = tMinZ;
                }
                if( !tMax.HasValue || tMaxZ < tMax )
                {
                    tMax = tMaxZ;
                }
            }
            if( ( tMin.HasValue && tMin < 0 ) && tMax > 0 )
            {
                return 0;
            }
            return tMin < 0 ? null : tMin;
        }

        public float? Intersects( BoundingSphere sphere )
        {
            Vector3 difference = sphere.Center - this.Origin;
            float differenceLengthSquared = DestinyEngineMath.LengthSquared( difference );
            float sphereRadiusSquared = sphere.Radius * sphere.Radius;
            float distanceAlongRay;
            if( differenceLengthSquared < sphereRadiusSquared )
            {
                return 0.0f;
            }
            Vector3 refDirection = this.Direction;
            Vector3.Dot( ref refDirection , ref difference , out distanceAlongRay );
            if( distanceAlongRay < 0 )
            {
                return null;
            }
            float dist = sphereRadiusSquared + distanceAlongRay * distanceAlongRay - differenceLengthSquared;
            return ( dist < 0 ) ? null : distanceAlongRay - ( float? )Math.Sqrt( dist );
        }

        public static bool operator !=( Ray a , Ray b )
        {
            return !(a.Origin.Equals( b.Origin ) && a.Direction.Equals( b.Direction ));
        }

        public static bool operator ==( Ray a , Ray b )
        {
            return a.Origin.Equals( b.Origin ) && a.Direction.Equals( b.Direction );
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "{{Origin:" + Origin + " Direction:" + Direction + "}}";
        }

        public void DrawImmediate()
        {
            Vector3 end = this.Origin + this.Direction * 400.0f;
            GL.Begin( PrimitiveType.Lines );
            GL.Vertex3( this.Origin );
            GL.Vertex3( end );
            GL.End();
        }
    }
}
```

Using these you can do something like:

```
Ray ray = new Ray(new Vector3(0, 0, 0), new Vector3(1, 1, 1));
            BoundingSphere sphere = new BoundingSphere(new Vector3(1,1,1), 0.5f );
            Console.WriteLine(ray.Intersects(sphere)); // Gives length until intersection.
```

The above code is written in C#, which can easily be ported over to Java. However, I don't know why anyone would use Java; it's a terrible language.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that tomorrow

Comment: @Nifil No problem! Good luck with your project!

Answer (score -1):

Your `ray` has to be the exact length of the vector `cmo`. So if your `ray` is normalized, you have to

```
ray = ray * lengthOfCmO
```

So turn your camera-sphere vector around, get your ray to the correct length and your function should work. You should note, that this formular isn't mathematically correct. You just check, if the projection of the ray on the camera-sphere vector is longer than the length of camera to sphere minus the sphere radius. It will work, but you have to use a bigger sphere than you actually want to be hit by the ray.

Comment: You make assumptions and suggestions that are completely wrong for the algorithm at hand.